# win32 application, exit code, suggest user to logoff and logon

Tags: authentication, winapi, exit-code, logoff

Looking in the [win32 system error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx), there are for example 1641 and 3010 to report a Windows restart.
(  you can read the application exit code, from Dos shell, with the variable %ERRORLEVEL%  )

Is there a code to report the user to logoff or better to redo the Windows login ?

I don't want to invent my custom code, but to use a known one. It is necessary to fair living with other system management software.

Many software management systems read and use the exit code to report application  behaviour.
For example : I want to report to the "windows eco-system" that my setup.exe need the user to logoff and logon again.
My setup hasn't a GUI but its exit code is read from the parent process and the parent process will decode the error and prompt the user.

BUT the parent process is a big vendor one, not mine, so to have a meaningful communication between the two processes I have to use well-knows codes, as from the microsoft list.

**SPOILER : I AM NOT LOOKING FOR RECOMMENDATIONS, BUT FOR THE SPECIFIC VALUE, IF THERE IS ANY USED BY VENDORS LIKE microsoft, symantec, etc...**

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Ask about your problem, not your proposed solution.

Comment: this is not *exit* codes but *error* codes. not the same

Comment: Exit code or error code, call as you wish, it is the code returned from the terminating application main.

Comment: Sorry this is a tight question about a specific code. Staying generics I got rumours, see another similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151006/windows-exit-code-for-dc-battery-power

Comment: Error codes are meaningful **only** within the Windows API. They have no meaning at all when returned from an application. Please state your **real** problem.

Comment: @IInspectable nope. see the microsoft link above : "System Error Codes"

Comment: The *"system"* is Win32. Once you leave that system, i.e. return from your application, those codes have **no meaning**. At all. There are no standard error return values. Please ask about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable There are common values, see the microsoft list. I update the question with an example.

Comment: I'm afraid, you are wrong on this one. What you need is a contract between your installer and the parent process. You will have to talk to the vendor of the parent process to come to an agreement. There is no standardized contract with respect to return codes on Windows, other than the **conventional** agreement, that zero indicates success, and non-zero reports an error.

Comment: By convention, a request for the user to log off is represented as a request for the system to be rebooted, presumably so that end users don't need to understand the distinction.  So IMO you should return 1641 if you've initiated the logoff, or 3010 if you want the user or the installer to do it.  You should however check the installer documentation in case it treats either or both of those codes as special cases.  It is also possible that the installer accepts special return codes as well as Win32 error codes, e.g., using NTSTATUS codes with the "customer defined" bit set.

Comment: @IInspectable is right, imho. You are confusing Win32 API return values with process exit code. Reread the comment from Remy Lebeau, in the question you linked.

Comment: Conventional agreement is sufficient for me and the products of our software vendors, like microsoft.

Comment: Does the *"big vendor"* party agree to your returning Win32 error codes from processes?

Comment: Yes, I am using their conventions. Sorry I don't uderstand if you really want to help or just pontificate ...

Comment: @IInspectable: this isn't particularly surprising, since in my experience most installers (if they return meaningful exit codes at all) do indeed return Win32 error codes.  There are admittedly some exceptions.  Those usually have to be special-cased by the system administrator, e.g., by telling the system management software to run a batch file that calls the installer rather than running the installer directly.

Comment: Massimo, regarding your latest edit, I don't think I've **ever** seen an installer that asked the user to log off rather than to reboot.  So you're unlikely to find much in the way of precedent.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I agree but there are thousands of documented values, I google and RTFM but not all of them. In our scenario it is useful to report to just logoff and logon, a full reboot is not mandatory.

Comment: @Massimo: We cannot help you if you withhold information, such as the product you are interfacing with, their published contracts, etc. You keep insisting that *"to have a meaningful communication between the two processes I have to use well-knows codes, as from the microsoft list"*. The first half of that sentence is true. The second makes it utterly wrong. There is no standard all processes adhere to. Every vendor makes up their own contracts for each and every one of their products. You aren't telling us, which ones those are, and this question needs to get closed.

Comment: I already looked through the list of codes, searching for any that included the word "log".  I found nothing relevant.

Comment: @HarryJohnston did you find a single list of all common codes used by microsoft and other vendors ? google-fu is tedious...

Comment: @IInspectable, it simply isn't true that "every vendor makes up their own contracts for each and every one of their products".  Most installers return Win32 error codes, and most system management tools *expect* the return value from an installer to be a Win32 error code.

Comment: Massimo, the MSDN link you provided in your question includes all valid Win32 error codes.  While some installers may return unique codes, either in addition to or instead of Win32 error codes, system management software is unlikely to recognize them, so they're unlikely to be of any use to you.  (Incidentally, it might be wise to edit your question to specify the specific system management product(s) that you want to support.  Without that information, IInspectable is justified in complaining that your question isn't complete.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The term *"installer"* wasn't even part of the initial question. And my statement, that every vendor makes up their own contract for their products is true. The fact that they largely agree to re-use an **unrelated** set of error codes doesn't change that, nor does it make Win32 error codes a contractual process exit code.

Comment: @IInspectable, the question was not well written, agreed.  Calling it "making up your own contract" when you just follow the de-facto standard seems an awfully big stretch, but, well, whatever.  The important point is that there are probably good reasons for the OP to want to return a Win32 error code in this particular scenario, can we move on?

Comment: Massimo, the bottom line is that if you need to support arbitrary system management products, there is no way to do what you're asking for.  If there is a *specific* system management product you need to support, you need to tell us which one it is.  (I think you'll be out of luck even then, but you never know.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you for your lookup. If you want to write down your quest and sources, I will accept it as the answer, even if results in "not found".

Comment: There isn't a specific SMS. We aren't rich and manage 1200 clients with a collage of SW from big and unknown vendors. There are setups, updates, automatic tasks, our management scripts, etc. We haven't a contract between the parts because it is  impossible. De-facto standards aren't perfect but we haven't mission critical systems; for our IT staff is preferable to look around and found common exit codes, not custom (avoid our RTFM !). At the moment I look for this exit code only for our troubleshooting. For us it is valuable to split procedures exiting and asking a reboot or just a new login.